# Activity transparente com touch

Tags: android

Coloquei uma imagem em uma `activity` ao qual deixei transparente, porém preciso que a movimentação ao tocar a tela do celular aconteça pois parece que a `activity` trava a ação do `touch`.

Comment: Como você está deixando a sua activity transparente? É programaticamente ou através do `/style.xml`?

Comment: É pelo arquivo AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: já tentou usar WindowManager?